# How to save poco uploaded file

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I want to upload file using poco library.

Now I have the uploaded file in the istream variable but I don't know how I can save it to a file?

Here is my code where i can get the length of the file.

```
void handlePart(const MessageHeader &header, std::istream &stream) {
    _type = header.get("Content-Type", "(unspecified)");

    if (header.has("Content-Disposition")) {

        std::string disp;
        NameValueCollection params;
        MessageHeader::splitParameters(header["Content-Disposition"], disp, params);

        _name = params.get("name", "(unnamed)");
        _fileName = params.get("filename", "(unnamed)");
    }

    CountingInputStream istr(stream);
    NullOutputStream ostr;
    StreamCopier::copyStream(istr, ostr);
    _length = istr.chars();


}
```

Also now it's 1 file uploaded in the form if there be more than 1 file how it will be managed in istream?

Now there is 2 days I'm searching and testing different ways but I couldn't find any way, please help to resolve this problem.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depend on #Abhinav question [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175164/poco-read-and-save-uploaded-files):

We can write save code like this:

```
if (fileName.length() != 0){

        std::ofstream fout( fileName, std::ios::binary);
        fileList.push_back(fileName);
        fout << stream.rdbuf() ;


        fout.close();
    }
```

But unfortunately it's working for one file if there is more than one this code can't catch correctly.